# UISearchBar in UIView in UIBarButtonItem does not work as expected

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem

Im trying to add UIsearchBar to my navigation controller. Also i wish to use cancel button of UISearchBar.

```
UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, searchBar.frame.size.height);
searchBar.translucent = NO;
searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
searchBar.delegate = self;
UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:searchBar.frame];
[myView addSubview:searchBar];
UIBarButtonItem* sbItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myView];    
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:chart,sbItem,nil]];
```

trouble that searchBar is inactive. it appears in navigation controller. But when i tap on it it does not response at any way. If i show cancel button it appears but also not clickable.

If i doesnt wrap UIsearchBar at UIView it work fine except it doesnt want to show me a cancel button.

**UPD**
IF i call

```
[searchBar becomeFirstResponder]
```

it goes to edit mode and shows me a cancel button and keyboard, but looks like view in which searchBar wrapped  changes it frame params and goes on 10px down from its original appearence. And change its background from trnsparent to blackopaque

Looks like a some kind of Voodoo... So simple action takes so much time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have mistaken at search bar frame,you took search bar height as searchBar.frame.size.height,but there was no height at that time,just change it like:

> ```
> UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
> searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40);
> searchBar.translucent = NO;
> searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
> searchBar.delegate = self;
> UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:searchBar.frame];
> [myView addSubview:searchBar];
> UIBarButtonItem* sbItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myView];    
> [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray  arrayWithObjects:chart,sbItem,nil]];
> ```
>
> i am sorry,i don't know what the chart is here,hope it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for idea. But not. This part is ok. Search bar renders where it must be rendered, so it's frame looks ok. It's only changes after it becomes a first responder. Main trouble that searchbar is inactive. When I tap on it it does not response at any way. Chart is just another UIBarButtonItem element and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I test. But it's not work all the same. I see only one solution at the moment - set searchbar as first responder when view controller appears, after that it becomes active. And correct wrapper view frame and its background after that. Not gracefull but it should work. Will test it today.

Comment: Sorry, i was inadvertence while testing.

Comment: Trouble was really in zero frame height. So one part of my trouble was my mistake and my inadvertence. Another part of my trouble is a Bug ( i mean the cancel button within searchbar and its workability within wrapper UIView and working unefficiency without it) bug was reported.

Comment: I wish I could upvote it 100 times. Due to 0 height I also was facing the same issue and banging my head for an hour.. Thanks to both asker and answerer..